# ksh: cannot execute a compiled c library

Tags: linux, aix

I downloaded 
http://stedolan.github.io/jq/ 
Linux 64 bit copy

and ftp to AIX server 64 bit.

```
$ chmod 777 jq
$ ./jq
ksh: ./jq: cannot execute
```

Does any one know what the problem is ?

Comment: You're trying to run a Linux binary on a AIX system?

Comment: Yes . Wont it work ?

Comment: I don't know. But that's not a programming question.

Comment: You should download the source code and compile it on your AIX

Comment: In addition to @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams comment about running Linux binaries on AIX systems, chances are the Linux 64-bit binary is for the x86_64/amd64 architecture, while there's a significant chance that your AIX system might be a POWER architecture...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will be compiling the source files,
as Linux 64-bit binary is for the x86_64/amd64 architecture, while there's a significant chance that AIX system might be a POWER architecture .